# Can not bake my fluid simulation to keyframes, blender 2.83

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, baking

I am new to blender and trying to bake the fluid simulation I made. However the option "bake to keyframes" is not allowed even when I selected all the objects. Can anyone help to figure out what's wrong with it?
Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's only for rigid bodies. Why are you trying to bake it to keyframes. If you are trying to capture a single frame of the animation you could always just duplicate the fluid domain and select apply to shape key in the modifier tab.

Comment: Actually I want to render an animation of the fluid simulation. I am still very confused by the mechanism of Blender, so I watched some tutorials about baking animation and clicking this button... Thanks